# Automatically redirected without proxy pass name while serving static files in express node js on apache2 server

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, proxy

I'm currently using apache2 on Ubuntu Server, and host node js apps with Proxy Pass Configuration in apache2 sites-available configuration.

I added this line in my server configuration

```
 ProxyPass /nodeapps http://localhost:3000
```

But when I'm trying to serve static files in my public directory like this,

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

It was automatically redirected without the proxypass name, so when I'm trying to open my

```
http://server-dns/nodeapps/help
```

I expect to get my /public/help directory, but it automatically redirected to

```
http://server-dns/help
```

So it return 404 Error

**Not Found**

The requested URL /help/ was not found on this server.

Comment: What is your directory structure? It looks like your proxy working fine.

Comment: sysadmin/nodejsapps/nodeapps/public/help. 
yes my proxy working fine, but when i tried to access public folder in my project, it automatically redirected without the proxy name
so http://server-dns/nodeapps/help becomes http://server-dns/help, because /help is not available so it returns 404 error

Answer (score 0):

As you specified in comment, it seems to either `index.html` is not available in `sysadmin/nodejsapps/nodeapps/public/help/` directory or problem in static path because your url http://server-dns/help is correct. So cross check bellow 2 points

> Is `sysadmin/nodejsapps/nodeapps/public/help/index.html` exist ?
>   Is correct path used for static? You may like to use `path` module as
>   bellow

```
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I hope this help you ):

Comment: yes index.html exists in sysadmin/nodejs/nodeapps/public/help/index.html
i tried used path, but t still doesn't work, when i try to access server-http://server-dns/nodeapps/help it still redirected to http://server-dns/help

Comment: yes i can access it on remote server, but not from client